# Simplify Blender GUI, FileWindow without info header

Tags: python

I want to use Blender for a specific task where the user (not me) is just presented with a limited set of tools and nothing else.

Using the usual possibilities configuring the GUI lead my quite close to my target.

Q: When using a FileWindow the info(window) bar ist still on top I would like to remove that too. It seems that Fileops (like load or import) are opening a maximized window (like with Shift-Spacebar). So is there a method to avoid this for all fileoperations? e.g. open the FileWindow just in the window it was called

Here an image: [image]

For my users this in the info bar (marked it **red**) is not usefull in this moment... They should not be able to change the render engine or browse the menu etc. but just open a file...

Thanks,
Carsten

Comment: Can you explain why this is important? / needed?

Comment: I need blender simplified so that a worker with a very specific task has no chance to make mistakes beside the (not trivial) task he is doing. And the support is much easier when you dont have to explain ALL buttons and functions in Blender.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to customize the window layout used when launching the file selector, unless you modify the C source code.

However Im not sure why this, specifically is such an important feature.

You could however, use Python's `tkinter` to launch a non-blender file-selector.

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685836/432509

Comment: I added an image, maybe I was not exact enough?

Comment: I will also look into the tkinter thingy.

Comment: bpy.context.area.type = 'FILE_BROWSER' is also interesting, but I did not find a way to use it a generic window, it seems always open as save file window.